# Remove anchor effect from a button inside a div which is clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a div which is totally click-able . But now I have added a button clicking on which a popup appears . But the problem which I am facing is that . When I click the info button the popup appears but also the page goes to the referenced page which is added to the outer most div .

My html code is here

```
<div style="cursor:pointer; background:" onclick="location.href='http://inmotico.com';" class="contenido_anuncio">
    Here if you click any where it will take you to the page
   <div style="font-size:14px;" class="anuncio_priceiimo">
<div style="margin-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" class="ui-btn-inline">

    <div style="margin-top: 10px;" class="ui-block-a"> <a class="ui-link" style="color: #FF6600;"></a><a style="color: #FF6600;" class="ui-link">¢ 217,277,650.00</a></div>
<div class="ui-block-b">
    <a style="border:none !important;margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;" data-shadow="false" title="info" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="info" data-role="button" href="#mDialog1" data-enhance="true" class=" ui-link ui-btn ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" data-rel="popup" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="mDialog1" aria-expanded="false" role="button">INFO</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a  [FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rKy97/4/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to learn not to use inline javascript when working with jQuery Mobile, it is a big no no.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NNj2T/

#### HTML:

```
<div style="cursor:pointer; background:"  class="contenido_anuncio" >
    Here if you click any where it will take you to the page
    <div style="font-size:14px;" class="anuncio_priceiimo">
        <div style="margin-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" class="ui-btn-inline">

            <div style="margin-top: 10px;" class="ui-block-a">
                <a class="ui-link" style="color: #FF6600;"></a><a style="color: #FF6600;" class="ui-link">¢ 217,277,650.00</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <a style="border:none !important;margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;" data-shadow="false" title="info" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="info" data-role="button"  data-enhance="true" class=" ui-link ui-btn ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="mDialog1" aria-expanded="false" role="button" id="info-btn">INFO</a>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="mDialog1" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-corners="true" data-dismissible="true">POPUP</div>

</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('vclick', '#info-btn',function(event) {
    $('#mDialog1').popup('open');
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$(document).on('vclick', '.contenido_anuncio',function(event) {
    location.href='http://inmotico.com';
    //alert('asdasd');
});
```

#### Links:

Learn about event propagation in javascript and jQuery **[here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** and [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/). Basically in this example if you do everything programmatically you don't need to worry about events misfiring.

Comment: but I am using a dynamic php code to show the details add page . Each add has different link so how I am going to add it in the vclick function ?? . I had tried something like this .... It works in fiddle but in my website an error is occurring when i click the button that is popup is not recognized as a function ... Any Idea why it happens

Comment: Let every link has a same identifier like class="special-link" or something and use it with my example. If you take a look at provided JavaScript example it is called a delegated event binding, it doesnt care of element exist or don't exist in DOM. As soon as element with given identifier is added to DOM that vclick event binding will work on it.

Comment: Sorry bro I am not getting you . I am confused where to add the Href:link then ? . Like right now its in the div tag itself so there are as many links as equal to number of div created in the page . How I should do this with your Javascript ? Like how to set the href

Comment: Should I add a listener for href attr() ??    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');

Comment: you mean href link to open popup?

Comment: No bro href for opening the add its like this <div href=//Link to details of the add/"><div dtat-role="info" dtat-rel="popup"></div>

Comment: You do understand that only a tags have href attribute? Can you add real HTML example (into your question) plus tell me what do you expect of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53959/discussion-between-vikram-anand-bhushan-and-gajotres)